# SSIS package SQL DB to a Excel Spreadsheet destination Unicode Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssis, etl

I have a DB OLE Source going to an excel destination. I receive the following error

> Error at Data Flow [Excel Destination [88]]: Column "X" cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types.

I have added in a data conversion to change string columns to Unicode. this has not resolved the problem. any guidance would be appreciated

Comment: You can see on your destination what type your column is under mapping. I would cast your source to the appopiate datatype. Eg. select cast(ColumName as nvarchar(50) as ColumnName from XXX.XXX - If it says error then i would delete your task and create again and write your paste your correct SQL inside your statement (It doesnt handle metadata well, so you need to update it by either deleting task or go to advanced options) this works fine for me.

Comment: Check the solution below. Add an alias of column in data conversion and map it in excel.

Comment: Can you post screenshot of your ssis solution? And screenshot from source and destination setup?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your excel destination component --> mapping --> hover your mouse over column in question, you'll see that it is `Unicode Str`. Something like this :

[image: img]

Hence, you need a `data conversion component` to add an alias of source column to `DT_WSTR Unicode String` **AND** map it in excel destination component.

[image: img2]

I replicated your problem and thus providing you solution.

**IF** this doesn't work, then delete these components and re-add them, as this is will mostly resolve your issue.

Comment: this is what I have done. but I am still getting this problem

Comment: Hope you've created alias and mapped it in destination. Try to remove them and repeat again (if possible, in another package). It sometimes happen that cache doesn't refresh.

Comment: thanks for you feedback, I have started right from the beginning and still no luck. I really cant see why this isn't working

Comment: Now it totally comes to hit and trial. Try a new excel file. If that also fails, I am really out of ideas :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a derived column instead of data conversion transformation, use the following expression

*If destination is unicode*

```
(DT_WSTR,50)[X]
```

*Else*

```
(DR_STR,50,1252)[X]
```